# Use column name and truncated date value in query

Tags: mysql, date

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `capstone`.`getRentalTransactions`(startDate DATE, endDate DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT * from rental_entry 
WHERE DATE(rental_date)=startDate
OR DATE(return_date)=endDate;
END$$
```

In this procedure I would like to get everything from the rental_entry table where the value of the rental_date column is equal to the `startDate` parameter or where the value of the return_date column is equal to the `endDate`parameter. Both `rental_date` and `return_date` are stored in the database as `datetime`. What can I change in this code to make that work?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: why wouldn't this work? You're converting your datetime values to dates, and comparing them to dates. Any reason you're thinking this won't work?

Comment: `FROM` keyword is missed- is it a typo?  It should be `SELECT * FROM rental_entry ....`, not just `SELECT * rental_entry ...`

Comment: @a1ex07 sorry, the missed `from` was a typo

Comment: I was thinking that the date function would simply convert the datetime value into a date value and not use the column name in the `startDate` or `endDate` comparison.

Comment: Yes. The `FROM` was missed when I copied and pasted the code. I will fix it in the question.

Comment: @JesseTurnbull What is not working? Do you get an error? If yes what is it?